# Limiting the mysql relational table

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables:

**Table: words** - more than 200, 000 rows

```
id word
1  a
2  b
3  c
4  d
and so on.
```

**Table: pos**

```
id part
1  noun
2  verb
3  adjective
4  adverb
and so on.
```

**definitions** - more than 500,000 rows

```
id wordid posid definition
1  1      1     The first letter of the Roman alphabet.
2  1      1     Blood group 'A'.
3  1      1     The abbreviation of Ace.
4  2      1     The second letter of the Roman alphabet.
5  2      1     The definitions of B go on.
```

I want the fastest query to limit the words but not the definitions. You help will be much appreciated.

I have tried:

```
SELECT word, part, definition 
FROM words, pos, definitions
WHERE words.id = wordid
AND pos.id = posid
ORDER BY word
LIMIT 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your help and time. I posted this question on another link and @B. Desai answered it right.
Here's the query I was looking for:

```
SELECT w.word,d.definition,d.pos FROM 
  (SELECT id, word FROM words ORDER BY id LIMIT 5) w 
  JOIN definition  d ON d.wordid = w.id
```

Here's the link: [How to limit words but not definitions using mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45852663/how-to-limit-words-but-not-definitions-using-mysql/45853028#45853028)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this query to retreive data faster:

```
SELECT w.word,p.part,d.definition
from  definitions d 
inner join pos p
on d.posid=p.id
inner join words w
on w.id=d.wordid
order by word
```

Difference between my code and your code:

One difference is that the first option hides the intent by expressing the join condition in the where clause.

The second option, where the join condition is written out is more clear for the user reading the query. It shows the exact intent of the query.

**The inner join syntax is preferable because it is easier on the reader, as others have already remarked and sometimes more faster like in your data**

As far as performance or any other difference, there shouldn't be any. Both queries should return the exact same result and perform the same under most RDBMS.

Edited:

Final Code is:

```
SELECT w.word,p.part,d.definition
from  definitions d 
inner join pos p
on d.posid=p.id
inner join words w
on w.id=d.wordid
order by word
WHERE 
(SELECT COUNT(*)
 FROM words w 
 WHERE w.id = d.wordid ) <=2
```

***I hope this code help you.***

Comment: I really appreciate your time and help. What I am stuck in is the LIMIT part. I would like to limit the words however I want to have as many definitions available as possible. As you can see, this is a dictionary website, and when I say "LIMIT 2", I want to limit to 'a' and 'b', but either 'a' or 'b' can have multiple definitions. I wonder if my question is not clear.

Comment: Your welcome, this SQL SELECT LIMIT example would select the first 2 records from these 3 tables.

Comment: I think you want to limit words table, If yes you can use this where cluase to limit it :    `WHERE (
  SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM words w
  WHERE w.id = d.wordid
) <=2`

Comment: You can change it and optmize it. I edited the answer with full code. I hope it can help you freind

Comment: May you please send me the result? I may see the problem. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your help, and I already got the answer. Here's the link: [Answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45852663/how-to-limit-words-but-not-definitions-using-mysql/45853028#45853028)