# How to limit words but not definitions using mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have two related tables called **words** and **definitions**. Each table has over 250,000 rows. Here's how my tables are setup.

**Words**

```
id word
 1 book
 2 love
 3 hate
 4 smile
 and it goes on.
```

**Definitions**

```
id wordid pos definition
 1 1      v   to enter in a book or list; record; register.
 2 1      n   a book, a bible
 3 2      n   noun definition of love
 4 2      v   verb definition of love
 and it goes on.
```

I wrote a php that select 5 results from words using:
 
`$query = "SELECT id, word FROM words LIMIT 5"`;

And then I loop each of the 5 results like

```
foreach($results as $row){
   $wordid = $row['id'];
   $word = $row['word'];

   // I really dont want to do this way
   $definitions_query = "SELECT * FROM definition WHERE wordid = $wordid";

   // After the query
   foreach($definitions_result as $row1){
       $definition = $row1['definition'];
       $pos        = $row1['pos'];

     // Desired Results
     $data[$word][$pos][] = $definition;
   }
}
```

My code accomplished the mission, but it's too slow.

So, I joined the tables like `"SELECT * FROM words JOIN definition ON words.id = wordid LIMIT 5"`.

Now, the query only pulls five results and I cannot limit the words to 5 rows.

My goal is to pull 5 words along with their many definitions in a very fast way. Please keep in mind of my desired result array format as well. How would I go about it? Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: First pull only five words then put a join with definition table.

Comment: @kkmishra would you mind typing the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query. It will limit parent data and join the tables

```
SELECT w.word,d.definition,d.pos FROM 
  (SELECT id, word FROM words ORDER BY id LIMIT 5) w 
  JOIN definition  d ON d.wordid = w.id
```